# i want change Key Store or make same with android studio

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

i create application by codename one in netBeans
and now i create another version by android studio the same project code
But after I uploaded to the store the next version they told me I must not
change app signatures
for the app key. Who made the key app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in your `codenameone_settings.properties` file. It includes the credentials of the keystore you created for Codename One. You can use this keystore in Android Studio for new builds.

Comment: when i do like you say i have this problem:  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key FastBrowserKey.jks from store

Comment: That's the keystore we use. I can't really help with Android Studio as I don't use it much myself in this way. I can tell you that if you include source in the Codename One build you get back an Android Studio project with a certificate that works.

Comment: you mean i make source code for my project in android studio and put the source code in codename one and build the application

Comment: No. If you make the code in Codename One and send a build with include source. You'll get a working native Android app (requires a basic subscription though).